# Modal help - Scroll bar not closing when modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently I am working on a website and when an administrator wants to make a news update, they select a button and it allows them to write the news update into the modal. This is all good, however since people have different screen-sizes, I need to ensure that the modal is able to be scrolled as the amount of data they are putting in is large.

To enable the scroll bar I have set the modal style as:

```
<div class="md-modal md-dark primary md-effect-3" id="md-fall" style="max-height: 90%; overflow-y: auto;">
```

When I open my modal using:

```
<button class="btn btn-rad btn-trans btn-primary md-trigger" data-modal="md-fall">Create a new changelog post</button>
```

it works fine, however when I go to close the modal using the "X" in the top right corner:

```
<button type="button" class="close md-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
```

the modal closes however the scroll bar on the side does not. I have been looking around for awhile and I cannot figure out how to get it to close with the rest of the modal.

I look forward to your help.

Thanks.

Comment: can you create fiddle or something similar to that

Comment: I can, but I have never touched Fiddle or written much JS. Sorry mate, I am a rookie when it comes to these visual parts. Any guidance would be helpful though.

Comment: Why dont you try this instead... http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals